# Using the Ito formula for the differential of a (function of) Brownian motion

Tags: calculus, differential

I am getting troubled about how to use the Ito formula for a function f=f(x,s):
$$
df(B_t,t)=f_t(B_t,t)dt+f_x(B_t,t)dB_t+(1/2)f_{xx}(B_t,t)dt
$$

Say for the function $f(x,t)=\cos(xt)$. We have the function 
$$
f(B_t,t)=\cos(B_tt)
$$

By applying the formula we get:
$$
df(B_t,t)=f_t(B_t,t)dt+f_x(B_t,t)dB_t+(1/2)f_{xx}(B_t,t)dt 
=-\sin(tB_t)B_tdt-\\ -\sin(B_tt)tdB_t-(1/2)\cos(B_tt)t^2dt
$$

Am I getting this right? Is this the right result?
If not, where have I messed up?

Thanks in advance for any replies :)